# R/purrr: conditional redistribution of columnar data using map

Tags: r, functional-programming, tidyverse, purrr

I've gotten really interested in learning (and eventually mastering) the `purrr` package. But despite having looked at quite a few tutorials ([1](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/functional-programming.html), [2](https://rdrr.io/cran/purrr/man/map.html), [3](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/), [4](https://emoriebeck.github.io/R-tutorials/purrr/)), I'm struggling to understand--and make use of--`purrr::map` (and functional programming in general).

My test scenario is a data frame containing two columns as shown below:

```
df <- data.frame("ColChars" = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), "ColNums" = c(1:6))
df
#   ColChars ColNums
# 1        A       1
# 2        B       2
# 3        C       3
# 4        A       4
# 5        B       5
# 6        C       6
```

What I'd like to do is use `map` (or `map_df`?) to rearrange the data in `ColNums` as follows:

```
df
#   ColChars ColNums
# 1        A    1, 4
# 2        B    2, 5
# 3        C    3, 6
```

I know I can do this easily with a for loop:

```
df <- data.frame("ColChars" = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), "ColNums" = c(1:6))
newdf <- data.frame(character(), character())
GrpVar <- unique(df$ColChars)
for(i in 1:length(GrpVar)){
  TmpColChars <- GrpVar[i]
  TmpColNums <- paste(df$ColNums[df$ColChars==GrpVar[i]], collapse=",")
  tmpdf <- data.frame(TmpColChars, TmpColNums, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  newdf <- rbind(newdf, tmpdf)
}
(newdf <- setNames(newdf, names(df)))

#   ColChars ColNums
# 1        A     1,4
# 2        B     2,5
# 3        C     3,6
```

How would I go about implementing this using `map`? (as an example) Or is an operation like this not appropriate for the `map` approach? I presume my problem is actually a severe lack of understanding (+misunderstanding of) methods like `lapply`, and I am hoping that the answers to this question will enable me to remedy this.

Comment: A `data.frame` is a special kind of list (columns are elements), `map` or `lapply` loop on these elements, what you want to do here is an aggregation, and in `tidyverse` idiom it's done using `group_by` and `summarize` from package *dplyr*, no need for package *purrr* or function *map* here. Is this what you want ? `df %>% group_by(ColChars) %>% summarize(ColNums = paste(ColNums, collapse=", "))`

Comment: I agree with other comments that `map` is not needed here. Though its use could be demonstrated with e.g. `df %>% split(.$ColChars) %>% map(~ paste(.$ColNums, collapse = ", ")) %>% unlist() %>% enframe()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

No need for `map` here:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(ColChars) %>% 
   summarise(ColNums = paste(ColNums, collapse = ", "))
```

---

**Answer Using `map`**

You can use `map` in this rather complicated way:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ColChars) %>% 
   tidyr::nest() %>% 
   mutate(ColNums = map_chr(data, ~ paste(.$ColNums, collapse = ","))) %>% 
   select(-data)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   ColChars ColNums
#   <fct>    <chr>  
# 1 A        1,4    
# 2 B        2,5    
# 3 C        3,6
```

*Explanation*

1. `group_by`: you want to do the rest of the pipe per `ColChar`
2. `nest`: you summarise the non grouping variables in a `tibble` which becomes a new column `data` in your result (`data` is a column which contains 3 `tibbles`)
3. now you `map_chr` through each element of data (which is a `tibble`) and for each `tibble` you extract column `ColNums` and paste that together.

*Note* you want a character vector and not a list that's why you use `map_chr` instead of `map`

---

**Better Explanation of How to use `map`**

As per the comments, it is not the best example for the usage of `map` as this can be solved better by `group_by` and `summarise`. Hence, here a more meaningful example to explain the benefits of `map`:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 100),
                x   = rnorm(300),
                y   = rnorm(300))
(d <- d %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(mod = list(lm(y~x))))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   grp   mod     
#   <fct> <list>  
# 1 A     <S3: lm>
# 2 B     <S3: lm>
# 3 C     <S3: lm>
```

Now assume that you want to get the adjusted R squared of each model. You may try:

```
d %>% mutate(ar = summary(mod)$adj.r.squared)
```

> ```
> Error in summary(mod)$adj.r.squared : 
>   $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> ```

However, this does not work, b/c `dplyr` is passing the whole column `mod` to `summary` and you are effectively doing `summary(d$mod)` which is not what you want.

This is where `map` becomes handy:

```
d %>% mutate(ar = map_dbl(mod, ~ summary(.)$adj.r.squared))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   grp   mod            ar
#   <fct> <list>      <dbl>
# 1 A     <S3: lm> -0.00763
# 2 B     <S3: lm>  0.00826
# 3 C     <S3: lm> -0.00843
```

Now you map through each element of  `mod` and extract the adjusted r square from the summary.

Comment: That's a stretch to use `nest` +  `map` + `mutate` when you have `summarize` :) (also don't forget library calls).

Comment: I think that will confuse OP more than anything else, better to explain what `map` does and why he doesn't need it here IMO.

Comment: I think the problem is that this solution depends on three packages.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I updated my answer accordingly.